# Using a variable from one PHP script as an argument for a PHP function i another PHP script

Tags: php

I am trying to set the value to be displayed in a SELECT list using php scripts.
What I have done is create an input html page (MatchSelect.php) which shows two select boxes and a submit button.
On pressing the submit button a new new php file is called (MatchSelectResult.php) which is as follows;

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Seniors Inter-Club Match Management</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"  href="MainBody.css">
<link href="dropDown.css?v=1.1" rel="stylesheet" >
<?PHP require '../../configure.php';
include "Main_PHP_Code.php" ;
?>

</head>

<body>
<?PHP include "MatchPopulate.php"; ?>
<div class="container">
    <?PHP include "menu.txt" ?>
    <div class="content">  
         <div>
            <h1>Team Selection</h1>
            <form name="matchSelect" method="POST" action="MatchUpdate.php">

            <p>&nbsp;
            <select id = "Venue" name= "Venue" >
                <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                        <option value="Away">Away</option>
                <option value="Home">Home</option>
              </select>
            match against 
                    <select id ="Opponents" name ="Opponents">
                            <?php 
                                Global $OpponentName;
                                $oop = $OpponentName;
                                opponent_load('$oop');
                                ?>
                </select> 
etc.
```

the function opponent_load() is contained within the "Main_PHP_Code.php" code and is as follows;

```
function opponent_load($oppon){
Global $OpponentName;  
$db_handle = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
$database = "matchmanagementdb";
$db_found = mysqli_select_db($db_handle, $database);
if ($db_found) {
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM opponentsdb";
$result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $SQL);
while ( $db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

    $uName = $db_field['Opponents'];
    if ($uName == $oppon)
    {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    }
    else
    {
        $selected = '';
    }
    echo "<option value='$uName' $selected> $uName </option>";
}
}
else {
    print "Database NOT Found ";
}
mysqli_close($db_handle);
}
```

The "MatchPopulate.php" code in the HEAD section is used to search the mySQL database using the two values from MatchSelect.php page. If the data is found, then the global variable $OpponentName is defined. The code is thus;

```
<?php 
Global $OpponentName;
//require '../../configure.php';
$uOpponentName = $_POST['Opponents'];
$uVenue = $_POST['Venue'];

//$db_handle = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
$database = "matchmanagementdb";
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// check to see if Match (Opponents + Venue)already in the database, if so, retrieve data or add match to database
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM teamselect WHERE Opponents = '$uOpponentName' AND Venue = '$uVenue'";
$result = $conn->query($SQL);
//if $result->num_rows >0 then retrieve data  ELSE add match to database
if (!$result){
    print "Error selecting record: " .  $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}   else {
        if ($result->num_rows >0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $OpponentName = $row['Opponents'];
                } 
            } else { 
                $sql = "INSERT INTO teamselect (Opponents, Venue) VALUES ('$uOpponentName', '$uVenue')";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                } else {
                    print "Error adding record: " .  $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }
            }
         } 
$conn->close();
?>
```

The code stops when it tries to populate the Opponents Select box on MatchSelectResult.php. Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please include the php error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error message. The html page stops loading at the point when the page loads the Select box for opponents.

Comment: Turn on error_reporting and read error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by opening  a session and using $_SESSION["Opponents"] to pass the variable around the scripts.
Also changed opponent_load('$oop') to opponent_load($oop).